# cannot pass value from function to variable

Tags: javascript, function, scope, callback, return

So, I have this code about an object

```
Obj.prototype.save = function (fn){

    var aabb = Obj.reEditName(this.name, function(newName) {
         return newName;
         // I also try the following
         var foo = newName; 
         return foo;
    });     
    console.log("aabb is  : "+aabb);

}

Obj.reEditName = function(name, fn){
    var name ? name : "TestingName";
    nameEditor(name,function(err, finalName) {
        return fn(finalName);
    });
}
```

`Obj.reEditName` works fine and I get a value back that I can get from `newName`.

But `console.log("aabb is  : "+aabb);` gives back undefined.

I dont get why. I get a value and I return it, and `aabb` suppose to catch it. Why this isnt working? How I can pass `newName` back to `aabb`?

Thanks

Comment: aabb is a function not a variable. You need to call the function with ().

Comment: @remus Can you be a little nore analytic on what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the definition of `reEditName`?

Comment: @Barmar Here you go.

Comment: `reEditName` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `return fn(finalName)` returns a value to `nameEditor`, it doesn't return from `reEditName`.

Comment: I suspect `nameEditor` is an asynchronous function, probably using an HTML form to edit the name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you get undefined is because, newName is undefined...
Let's take a look at your code.

```js
Obj.prototype.save = function (fn){

    //I suppose here you are assigning aabb the result of reEditName.
    //because you are calling it...
    var aabb = Obj.reEditName(this.name, function(newName) {
         //you have a callback as a second parameter, and this callback recevied an argument (newName)...
         return newName;
         // I also try the following
         var foo = newName; 
         return foo;
    });     
    console.log("aabb is  : "+aabb);

}
```

**The problem here is, when you are calling that callback from your reEditName method is not receiving that newName parameter, or it is receiving undefined for some other reason.**

Possible solution:

```js
Obj.reEditName = function(name, callback) {
  //you should call that callback with an argument, and return it...
  return callback('New name');
}
```

Comment: Yes my `reEditName` is like that. And if I do ` console.log("newName  > "+newName);` inside the `var aabb = Obj.reEditName(this.name, function(newName) {` and before the ` return newName;` I get the value that I should have. Are you sure the problem is there?

Comment: I adjusted the answer's solution to fit that.

Comment: I also did what you said, but `console.log("aabb is  : "+aabb);` still gives undefined.

Comment: I will test it right now. Thanks for your time. I dont know if it changes anything, but I added the definition of `Obj.reEditName `. Check my original question

Comment: return nameEditor and check if name editor return the second parameter which is the callback, as you do in reEditName...

Comment: Can you please edit your jsbin code, because I am lost? Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99551/discussion-between-miguel-lattuada-and-user2860857).